# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number - Python insert query

Tags: python, oracle

I am executing following code in python(in eclipse) using oracle 11.g database. I am getting error: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number.
Please help

```
addressid=input("Enter address id:")
    addressLine=input("Enter Address line:")
    city=input("Enter city:")
    zipcode=input("enter zipcode:")
    state=input("ENTER state")

    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO 
INFYCAMPUSCONNECT.Address(ADDRESSID,ADDRESSLINE,CITY,ZIPCODE,STATE)
                   VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)""",
                   (addressid,addressLine,city,zipcode,state))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392288/databaseerror-ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-number)

Comment: I am not  able to understand that solution. Can you explain the issue again.

Comment: See here for the different ways to bind variables in cx_Oracle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868717/python-cx-oracle-bind-variables