# Illegal variable name/number when binding dictionary

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am currently getting a couple errors with my insert using cx_Oracle for python 3.6

```
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

and

```
ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name
```

Here is my code:

```
    def load_wp_sql(self, wp_dict):
        self.db.begin()
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        sql = """INSERT INTO work_package_work_table
                 (CONTROL_ACCOUNT, CONTROL_MANAGER, WP_MANAGER,
                  TITLE, WORK_STATEMENT, TYPE,
                  RISK_MITIGATION_SCOPE)
                 VALUES
                 (:control_account, :cam, :wp_manager,
                  :wp_title, :statement_of_work,
                  :wp_type, risk_mitigation_scope)
              """ 
        try:
            for wp in wp_dict:
                cursor.prepare(sql)
                cursor.execute(None, wp)
            self.db.commit()
        except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
            self.db.rollback()
```

This is the dictionary I am trying to bind, it is passed into the function as a generator object.

```
{
  'cam': 'CA Manager', 
  'control_account': 'W80.11.11.01.LL', 
  'risk_mitigation_scope': 'No', 
  'statement_of_work': 'For setup and maintainance of of the W80 EVMS Tools', 
  'wp_manager': 'cohagan1', 
  'wp_title': 'EVMS Tools', 
  'wp_type': 'Discrete'
}
```

I've looked a quite a few stackoverflow posts:
[Python cx_Oracle bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868717/python-cx-oracle-bind-variables)

[DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392288/databaseerror-ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-number)

As well as their documentation:https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html

I'm pretty sure I am just missing something simple but can't seem to find it.

Comment: I would check what is the actual command (string) you try to execute, I have the feeling you are not building the string you think you do.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `:` on the `risk_mitigation_scope` variable.

Comment: @Blorgbeard yes that was it, thank you