# why I get this error when I have exact table structure in database?

Tags: python, oracle, insert

i am trying to insert data in database

```py
con = cx_Oracle.connect('---------')
cur = con.cursor()

var1=3
var2=4

cur.execute('''
                insert into some_table (E,ECA_ID,E3,E4,E5,ARD_,ARD_N,ARD_NA,CARD_N,NAME,RANKNUM) 
                VALUES
                (1,%d,%s,4,5,'1','w','d','g', 'f',1)
                ''',(var1,var2))
con.commit()
```

and it gives me error

> DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

so when i tried it with code

```py
con = cx_Oracle.connect('---------')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('''
                insert into some_table (E,ECA_ID,E3,E4,E5,ARD_,ARD_N,ARD_NA,CARD_N,NAME,RANKNUM) 
                VALUES
                (1,1,3,4,5,'1','w','d','a', 'b',1)
                ''')
con.commit()
```

it works, so what is problem?

i am working in jupyter notebook, win 10

Comment: what about changing `%d` to `%s` ...

Comment: no, it says same as before

Comment: Are you sure `%d` and `%s` are allowed? Different implementations of the Python DB-API are allowed to use different placeholders. If I look at [`cx_Oracle.paramstyle`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) it says "named", so you have to follow the Oracle rules here: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#sqlexecution

Answer (score 1):

I never use oracle, but I think it's possible that you should scape %d,%s to '%d','%s'.

When you use '%' in a string (in java, for example) means a pattern to format the output.

Or maybe here [DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392288/databaseerror-ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-number) there's some solution to a problem very similar.

Regards,
Juliano.