# cxOracle: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I have problem with simple variable binding in my code:

```
conn_str = (f"oracle+cx_oracle://{self.params.user}:{urllib.parse.quote_plus(self.params.password)}"
            f"@{self.params.host}:{self.params.port}/?service_name={self.params.service}")

self.engine = create_engine(conn_str)

with self.engine.connect() as conn:
    s = text("""TRUNCATE TABLE :t1""")
    conn.execute(s, t1=table_name)
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-01036: illegal variable    name/number
[SQL: TRUNCATE TABLE :t1]
[parameters: {'t1': 'hss_prod'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

I've revieved documentation:

- https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html

and simmilar issues:

- https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/433
- [DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392288/databaseerror-ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-number)

and can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not allow bind variables in DDL statements. This is mentioned in the linked cx_Oracle documentation on binding and reads as follows:

```
Bind variables also cannot be used in Data Definition Language (DDL) 
statements, such as CREATE TABLE or ALTER statements.
```

And yes, a truncate table statement is a DDL statement! So your only option is to do something like this:

```
sql = f"truncate table {table_name}"
cursor.execute(sql)
```

If the value for `table_name` comes from an unknown source, make sure it is validated in order to avoid SQL injection!

Comment: But make sure you use an allow-list to validate `table_name` so you don't get SQL Injection security issues.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I've adjusted my answer to include that important note.